# IOS 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following log in log console.How can I get rid of this?

```
duplicate symbol _DeviceSystemMajorVersion in:
/Users/byteera/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/18_carati-esuxxyrbnzcfuwfkmqrndokpuzlr/Build/Intermediates/18 carati.build/Debug-iphoneos/18 carati.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NMRangeSlider.o
/Users/byteera/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/18_carati-esuxxyrbnzcfuwfkmqrndokpuzlr/Build/Intermediates/18 carati.build/Debug-iphoneos/18 carati.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Stepped_Slider_Bar.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Stepped_Slider_Bar` your custom view? Trying to declare the _DeviceSystemMajorVersion with a prefix:

```
// Stepped_Slider_Bar.m
#define SteppedSliderBar_DeviceSystemMajorVersion   xxxx
```

Comment: Thnx Bannings  my problem is solve it's major problem but i can't show this problem thanking you.. 

Nilesh Kasvala